# Checking image mime, size etc in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have found here a pretty good way of checking whether the file uploaded by the user is a picture or not, how ever I ran into problems when I tried implementing it.

Here is the class I have found to check files

```
public static class HttpPostedFileBaseExtensions
{
    public const int ImageMinimumBytes = 512;

    public static bool IsImage(this HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
    {            
        //-------------------------------------------
        //  Check the image mime types
        //-------------------------------------------
        if (postedFile.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/jpg" &&
                    postedFile.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/jpeg" &&
                    postedFile.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/pjpeg" &&
                    postedFile.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/gif" &&
                    postedFile.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/x-png" &&
                    postedFile.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/png")
        {
            return false;
        }

        //-------------------------------------------
        //  Check the image extension
        //-------------------------------------------
        if (Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName).ToLower() != ".jpg"
            && Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName).ToLower() != ".png"
            && Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName).ToLower() != ".gif"
            && Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName).ToLower() != ".jpeg")
        {
            return false;
        }

        //-------------------------------------------
        //  Attempt to read the file and check the first bytes
        //-------------------------------------------
        try
        {
            if (!postedFile.InputStream.CanRead)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (postedFile.ContentLength < ImageMinimumBytes)
            {
                return false;
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
            postedFile.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 512);
            string content = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            if (Regex.IsMatch(content, @"<script|<html|<head|<title|<body|<pre|<table|<a\s+href|<img|<plaintext|<cross\-domain\-policy",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Multiline))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        //-------------------------------------------
        //  Try to instantiate new Bitmap, if .NET will throw exception
        //  we can assume that it's not a valid image
        //-------------------------------------------

        try
        {
            using (var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(postedFile.InputStream))
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

My profile class

```
public class Profile
{
    public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a profile name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a intro")]
    public string Intro { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
}
```

My ProfileController after I have changed it. I added `HttpPostedFileBase`  as an argument and also used this line, `if (HttpPostedFileBaseExtensions.IsImage(file) == true)` , which I thought would sort it out but did not do any difference.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Profile profile, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (HttpPostedFileBaseExtensions.IsImage(file) == true)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {               

                        repository.SaveProfile(profile);
                        TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", profile.Name);
                        return RedirectToAction("List");
                    }
                 else
                    {
                        // there is something wrong with the data values
                        return View(profile);
                    }
            }
        else
        {
            return View(ViewBag);
        }            
    }
```

And finally the `SaveProfile` method from the repository.

```
public void SaveProfile(Profile profile)
    {
        Profile dbEntry = context.Profiles.Find(profile.ProfileID);                        
        if (profile.ProfileID == 0)
        {
            context.Profiles.Add(profile);
        }
        else
        {
            if (dbEntry != null)
            {                    
                    dbEntry.Name = profile.Name;
                    dbEntry.Rate = profile.Rate;
                    dbEntry.Intro = profile.Intro;
                    dbEntry.Description = profile.Description;
                if (profile.ImageData != null)
                {

                    dbEntry.ImageData = profile.ImageData;
                    dbEntry.ImageMimeType = profile.ImageMimeType;
                }                                                               
            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I also tried to edit the `SaveProfile` method, but could not implement all functions as in the class and would rather just have that separate and use it as it is. Any ideas where did I go wrong?

Comment: check it in debugger

Comment: I tried console debugging or what:), but didnt really understand much of it. Webapp works without errors! When i upload a file it will save it and all, but it will work with any file. If i upload an exe file, it still works. In database i can see the mime has nothing to do with a picture, so in my 'ProfileController' the first line do not do anything. It should separate the file from the profile instance and send it to check it, if it comes back true, than it should save it.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a number of issues, some major, some minor.

First and foremost, you're using the extension method wrong. The whole point of adding an extension is that it becomes a method off an instance of that type. The `this` keyword param, is implicit, and is filled by the back-referencing the object the method is called from, not passed explicitly. In other words, what you should have for your conditional is:

```
if (file.IsImage())
{
    ...
```

Notice also that there's no comparison with `true`. While there's nothing wrong with that, it's completely unnecessary, you already have a boolean.

Second, while placing this conditional around the rest of the code should be effective to prevent the object being saved, it provides no guidance to the user. Instead, you should do something like:

```
if (!file.IsImage())
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("file", "Upload must be an image");
}

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ...
```

By adding an error to `ModelState`, not only do you cause `IsValid` to be false, but now an actual error message will be presented to the user when the form is returned again.

Third, by attempting to select an existing profile instance from the database, you'll either get that instance or null. Therefore, you don't need to check whether `ProfileId` is 0, which is a pretty fragile check anyways (a user could merely change the hidden field's value to something else to modify an existing item). Instead, just do:

```
    var dbEntry = context.Profiles.Find(profile.ProfileID);                        
    if (dbEntry == null)
    {
        // add profile
    }
    else
    {
        // update profile
    }
```

Fifth, you're never doing anything with `file`. At some point, you should be doing something like:

```
var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
dbEntry.ImageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.InputStream.Length);
dbEntry.ImageMimeType = file.ContentType;
```

Finally, and this is more stylistic than anything, but excessive use of `else` blocks that are unnecessary makes your code harder to read. You can simply let the error case fall through. For example:

```
if (!file.IsImage())
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("file", "Upload must be an image");
}

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // save profile and redirect
}

return View(profile);
```

The first conditional will either add an error or not to `ModelState`. Then, in the second conditional, the code will only run if there's no errors, then it returns, so you never hit the final `return View(profile)`. However, if there's any validation errors, you just fall through to that final return. No `else` is necessary, and the code is much more concise and readable.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I corrected most the things you have suggested, but it still wont work. Extension method has been corrected, else statements removed, `ModelState.AddModelError` has been added as well, however it still wont do nothing. If I try to upload something other than a picture, it will save it without any error coming up. As I have mentioned before, I am new to MVC, but it seems like `HttpPostedFileBase file` argument in my controller is null. Seems like just by adding an argument to the action method, wont do the job. Any idea how to separate it?

Comment: Adding Adding `public HttpPostedFileBase file {get;set;}` to `public class Profile` ?

Comment: You could do that, but it functionally makes no difference. If your file parameter is coming in null, then either your file input's name attribute doesn't match or you're missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form element.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the multiple errors in your code as pointed out in Chris Pratts answer, your wanting to perform validation so the correct approach is to use a `ValidationAttribute` that implements `IClientValidatable` so that you get both server side and client side validation.

An example of a attribute that validates the file type is

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class FileTypeAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private const string _DefaultErrorMessage = "Only the following file types are allowed: {0}";
    private IEnumerable<string> _ValidTypes { get; set; }

    public FileTypeAttribute(string validTypes)
    {
        _ValidTypes = validTypes.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim().ToLower());
        ErrorMessage = string.Format(_DefaultErrorMessage, string.Join(" or ", _ValidTypes));
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (file != null)
        {
            var isValid = _ValidTypes.Any(e => file.FileName.EndsWith(e));
            if (!isValid)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessageString);
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ValidationType = "filetype",
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("validtypes", string.Join(",", _ValidTypes));
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

Then add the following script to your view

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('filetype', ['validtypes'], function (options) {
    options.rules['filetype'] = { validtypes: options.params.validtypes.split(',') };
    options.messages['filetype'] = options.message;
});

$.validator.addMethod("filetype", function (value, element, param) {
    if (!value) {
        return true;
    }
    var extension = getFileExtension(value);
    return $.inArray(extension, param.validtypes) !== -1;
});

function getFileExtension(fileName) {
    if (/[.]/.exec(fileName)) {
        return /[^.]+$/.exec(fileName)[0].toLowerCase();
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Then use a view model that includes a property for your file and apply the attribute

```
public class ProfileVM
{
    [FileType("jpg, jpeg, gif")] // add allowed types as appropriate
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

And in the view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.File)
```

If client side validation is enabled, you will get an error message and the form will not submit. If its disabled, A `ModelStateError` error will be added by the `DefaultModelBinder` and `ModelState` will be invalid and the view can be returned.

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort, but it is still hard to understand as I am new to MVC. I ran into a problem straight away, as soon as I try to add `public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }`  to `Profile class` it comes up with an error. I have separated this into two projects, domain and webui, in the `ProfileController` (which is in the webui project), I can use `HttpPostedFileBase` by `using System.Web;`, but in the profile class (domain project), it wont let me. Even if I add correct reference, wont use it, only allowed `HttpPostedFileBaseModelBinder`. I dont know what to do

Comment: Your missing an important part, which is **use a view model**. Refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc). You should never use data models in the view

Comment: I am using a `ProfileListViewModel` but it needs to contain all attributes from profile class as need to work with `ProfileId`. My main goal to check file still wont work

Comment: Your `ProfileVM` class should contain only those properties your need in the view, which means it would not contain properties `byte[] ImageData` and `string ImageMimeType` from the data model (your not editing them) but it would include `HttpPostedFileBase File`

Comment: Now I understand it, I will try it that way

Comment: Also in your question, you seem to wanting to validate the file size. [This article](http://www.bradwestness.com/2014/09/24/client-side-file-upload-validation/) shows you how to create a validation attribute to do that.